# int transforms into int&?

Tags: c++

code snippet:

```
// some code
SDL_Surface* t = Display->render_text(text);
int z=100;
Display->blit_image(t,z,100);
// some more code
```

does not compile because z magically changes to an int&,
file.cpp:48: error: no matching function for call to ‘display::blit_image(SDL_Surface*&, int&, int)

how can this happen?

post scriptum:
the following works if i put them in place of Display->blit_image(t,z,100)

Display->blit_image(t,z,100,0);

but i am sure that th 4th param is optional because the exact same function works elsewhere without it

pps: i created a minimal-case of my code that behaves as describd above
it's 3 files:

monkeycard.cpp: http://pastebin.com/pqVg2yDi

display.hpp: http://pastebin.com/xPKgWWbW

display.cpp: http://pastebin.com/nEfFX1wj

g++ -c display.cpp monkeycard.cpp fails with:
monkeycard.cpp: In member function ‘void monkeycard::messagebox(std::string)’:
monkeycard.cpp:28: error: no matching function for call to ‘display::blit_image(SDL_Surface*&, int&, int)’
display.hpp:26: note: candidates are: void display::blit_image(SDL_Surface*, int, int, SDL_Rect*)

Comment: How is `blit_image` declared?

Comment: void display::blit_image(SDL_Surface* img, int x=0, int y=0, SDL_Rect* clip=NULL) {
// code

Comment: Does `Display->blit_image(t,int(z),100);` work?

Comment: Does the compiler error message suggest any candidates ("`note: candidates are:` ... ")? If not, could you have typoed `blit_image` somewhere?

Comment: Is that the exact code that you are using, or is that 'an example'?

Comment: this is, in fact the exact code, copy and pasted from my code.

Comment: and the candiates are: note: candidates are: void display::blit_image(SDL_Surface*, int, int, SDL_Rect*)

Comment: Are your parameter defaults declared in the header file where the display class is defined or only in the source file where the blit_image member function is defined?

Comment: Please don't use external sites for critical parts of your question. Please put the code into the body of your question itself.

Comment: Is NULL properly defined where blit_image is declared? You can run the file through the preprocessor to check how the declaration looks like after preprocessing stage (NULL is #defined).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having seen the code, the defaults should be given in the header and not in the implementation file.

When you are compiling "monkeycard.cpp", the compiler has only the information in the headers to work with. The compiler has no idea that `blit_image` has default arguments, and therefore cannot match the function to call.

Answer (score 4):

The error message tells you what you're trying to pass. With automatic conversions and whatnot, that doesn't mean the function must have exactly that signature.

`int&` here just means that the parameter you've provided is an lvalue, and so it *could* be passed as a non-const reference. A function can match with that parameter as an `int&`, `const int&`, `int`, `long`, `const float&`, etc.

> the point is that if instead of z i
>   write 100 it works.

That's interesting. I can't immediately think of a way to write a function that accepts an integer literal, but not an integer variable. The following code compiles, of course:

```
struct SDL_Surface;
struct SDL_Rect;

struct display {
    void foo(SDL_Surface* img, int x=0, int y=0, SDL_Rect* clip=0) {}
};

int main() {
    display d;
    int z = 0;
    SDL_Surface *p = 0;
    d.foo(p,z,100);
}
```

So there must be something else you haven't mentioned yet, which causes the issue.

Edit: visitor and Charles Bailey (in a comment) have the answer. The defaults are missing from your declaration of the function, so as far as the compiler is concerned you are trying to call a 4-parameter function with 3 arguments. The `&` is not the problem.

For future reference: when James McNellis asked you for "the" declaration of your function, he meant the declaration which is visible in the translation unit making the call. In your pastebin code, the *definition* is not visible in that translation unit, and the compiler cannot reach in to a completely different .cpp file and realise that the function is supposed to have parameter defaults. In C++, default values are set up in the calling code, for reasons to do with how calling conventions work.

Comment: i do not follow. i defined blit_image to take a pointer to an SDL_Surface and after that optionally two ints ( and a pointer to a SDL_Rect ). I provided it with the first and two ints but it complains that z is a int& in line 48 where line 47 says: int z=100;

Comment: @lorb: `int&` vs `int` is the notation which gcc uses to distinguish the lvalue argument (z) from the rvalue argument (100). It doesn't mean that the compiler thinks you've actually declared `int &z = something`.

Comment: @Steve: If you declare `z` as `int&`, the *expression* `z` is still of type `int`, *not* `int&`. See ISO03 section 5 paragraph 6

Comment: @FredOverflow: what does that have to do with the price of fish? Nobody, including gcc, has suggested that the type of anything is `int&`. Neither has anyone declared any variables as `int&`. Evidently gcc's error message is misleading, since it has misled lorb, but it's useful :-)

Comment: Oh, in my comments I've assumed gcc, without lorb actually saying that, because I was checking it on gcc and the error message is exactly the same. If the compiler is something else, though, it's clearly using the same notation.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the function isn't declared properly.

There needs to be a prototype inside the `class display` scope such as:

```
void blit_image(SDL_Surface* img, int x=0, int y=0, SDL_Rect* clip=NULL);
```

When you pass an `int &` parameter (such as any named variable of type `int`) to an `int` argument, the value of the `int &` is copied into the new object of type `int`. The difference in types implies a conversion which entails a copy which implements pass-by-value. That is just how the C++ formalism works.

Answer (score 1):

The error message you see is nothing else than a specific convention, which that particular compiler uses to generate error messages in cases like that. Apparently, when the compiler is unable to resolve a function call, it generates an error message where every Lvalue argument is reported as having reference type and every Rvalue argument is reported as having non-reference type. This makes some sense, since references in C++ exist specifically for implementing the concept of run-time-bound Lvalue. In fact, it might even turn out that this is exactly how the overload resolution is implemented internally in that compiler.

As for the reason for the error: the function you are trying to call does not exist (or exists, but has a non-matching set of parameters).

P.S. You said in the comments that the matching function actually does exist. That would mean that there's either a problem with the visibility of the function declaration, or a problem with the code you posted being "fake" (i.e. it is not the code you were actually compiling).

Answer (score 0):

Primitives are not reference types in C++.

How do you know that it's the `int&` that's the cause for the error?  The error simply says that the signature is in error.  I'd recommend going back and checking the method signature to see what the root cause is.